# Dismiss a UIViewController that is hidden -- iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to figure out how to dismiss a view controller that is currently hidden, i.e. a  view originating from a modal segue is covering it.

Here's my situation: I only allow orientation changes for one view in my application. Lets call that view, View A. View A segues to a different viewController when it turns to landscape, and then I just dismiss the landscape viewController when it turns back to portrait.

The problem is: View A is embedded in a tabBarController and it is always the first view to load. If the user loads the app in landscape, view A will still appear in portrait even though it is clearly in landscape (which is fine). But, when i make an orientation to the landscape view and come back to View A, the tabBar is stuck in landscape.

So here I've decided to have an introView controller which figures out if the app is in landscape or portrait, and then either loads the landscape view or view A (the portrait view). Now, I could just segue between the two views every time, but I've heard this is bad practice (i.e. viewControllers are stacking up and constantly creating new instances).

I want to remove the intro view controller from the view hierarchy and then keep the same paradigm between the view A controller and the landscape view controller. Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?